# Stylelint multiline comments rule

Tags: css, sass, lint, stylelint

Today we use style validation with the sass-lint module, but we're migrating to stylelint.

One of the validations that sass-lint does in our projects is not allowing multi-line comments but allow one-line comments.

I need to know if there is any way to apply rule similar to stylelint.

Example:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
/* several lines comments should not be allowed */
$cor: #fff;

.test {
  color: $cor;
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
}
</style>
```

The comment in the above block should be consisted of stylelint, just as it is in sass-lint.

[code gif illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HmI2.gif)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if there is any way to apply rule similar to stylelint.

There is no equivalent rule in stylelint.

However, stylelint is extensible via [its plugin system](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/). You can create a plugin for your specific use case. You'll find examples of working with non-standard comments within the [double-slash rules](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-scss#-comment) in the [stylelint-scss plugin pack](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-scss).